# How to kick off a migration project? 

Tags: 2007, wiki, migration

I have a request for a migration project.

My client has a mechanism for Wikis.

So they are looking at the feasibility of migrating existing data from wiki onto SharePoint site server. So how can I start off with this project?

Comment: What is their current Wiki platform?

Comment: What is the mechanism and how does it work?

Comment: Charles and Mike have asked some question so 'll check back and wait till you reply.
If its a sharepoint WIKI then its feasible..

Comment: Services has a NetWiki site (resides on a server) which is the Knowledge Base .So i am looking for migrating existing data from Netwiki onto SharePoint site server

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this.  If you can export the content from their existing wiki you could make a powershell script to create the pages in a wiki page library but this would be pretty crude as any links, images and the like would be broken.  Again, you could use script to update linkages as the pages are created but then you're getting into some pretty complex parsing.  You'd have to balance the effort required to develop the transformation against the amount of content to be processed.